# Pass HTML and jinja iterator from flask to jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to make a page the most generic as possible so i can reuse it.I tough that i could do something like this:

```
    colunas = '<div class="row justify-content-around">\
                        <div class="col-sm-1" align="left">\
                            {{ x.utente_id }}\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-sm-11" align="left">\
                            {{ x.utente_nome }}\
                        </div>\
                    </div>'

return render_template("stuff.html", colunas=colunas)
```

And then using JINJA i could do something like:

```
{% for x in LIST_A %}
{{colunas}}
{% enfor %}
```

Ofcourse this returns the string "coluna" x times:

{{ x.utente_id }}   {{ x.utente_nome }}     {{ x.utente_id }}   {{ x.utente_nome }}     {{ x.utente_id }}   {{ .....

If i use the safe option

```
 {% for x in LIST_A %}
    {{colunas|safe}}
    {% enfor %}
```

The HTML code is correctly rendered but the parameters "{{ x.utente_id }}" are assumed as strings:

```
{{ x.utente_id }}
{{ x.utente_nome }}
{{ x.utente_id }}
{{ x.utente_nome }}
{{ x.utente_id }}
{{ x.utente_nome }}
```

Any Idea how i can make Jinja2 to recognize them as attributes from the obj x?

Thanks
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good place for Jinja [macros](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#macros), this should do what you need, and it will keep the html outside of your view logic.

Here's something to get you started (in your html file):

```
{% macro generate_coluna(x) %}
<div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-sm-1" align="left">
        {{ x.utente_id }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11" align="left">
        {{ x.utente_nome }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}

<html>
...

{% for x in LIST_A %}
    {{ generate_coluna(x) }}
{% endfor %}

...
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you , but you solution will assume that all the objects have those attributes not allowing to pass other object types.